# Do ints differ from strings when type hinting in PHP

Tags: php, type-hinting

I've been experimenting with type-hinting in PHP and came across something when doing some tests. I have this function:

```
function foobar(string $foo)
{
    return gettype($foo);
}
```

I have experimented with two uses:

```
echo foobar(4);
echo foobar('hello, world');
```

Both of these output `string`. This instantly screams weird to me, because I pass an integer in my first use. I then, for kicks tried adding:

```
print_r(foobar(['hello']));
```

and sure enough I got the fatal error I was expecting with the first case use.

Taken from [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) it shows that int is different from a string:

```
+=======+==================================+
| int   | The parameter must be an integer |
+=======+==================================+
|string | The parameter must be a string   |
+=======+==================================+
```

So why does `string $foo` allow my `foobar(4)` and return `string`?

Comment: Look up "strict types"

Comment: @Don'tPanic hmm I see ...... that leads me to the question of: are they worth enabling if they're disabled by default? Seems to me that, if they were something of great use and standard, it would be enabled on servers by default .. what are the drawbacks of strict types? (I guess that's a completely different question that I can research in my own time ..)

Comment: Just my opinion, but I don't think you really get the full benefit of type declaration without enabling strict types. I think part of the point of a type declaration is that it makes it more evident when a function is being used incorrectly, and without enforcing the typing it doesn't do that as well.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ah I see! Wasn't aware of it, but will start using strict type more often :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [PHP 7.0 introduced](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) scalar type declarations and, in an effort to begin moving away from its messy loose typing, provided a "strict" mode. The default "coercive" mode lets PHP remain as loose as ever though.

When you specify the string type for the argument in coercive mode, you're telling PHP that you want the argument to be a string, and that it should try and make it a string if it's not.

By adding the [declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) as the first line of your code, you can change the mode to get the desired behaviour:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

function foobar(string $foo)
{
    return gettype($foo);
}

try {
    echo foobar(4);
} catch (\TypeError $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```